# Css effects is not working in react application

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I implemented a form in a react application which has two fields, one for username and one for a password. Both have labels over the text field. Once the user clicks the text field the label is supposed to shift up a little bit and also decrease in size and change color. I have an HTML and css mockup already which works fine but once I implemented it in the react application, it doesn't work, and the color is already changed without having to click the text field
[image]

```
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}


.box {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   width: 500px;
   padding: 40px;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.box h2
  {
   margin: 0 0 0px;
   padding: 0;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
  }

 .box .inputBox{
    position: relative;
  }

 .box .inputBox input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
 }

  .box .inputBox label{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 10px 0;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: white;
     pointer-events: none;
     transition: .5s;
    }
.box .inputBox input:focus ~ label, //this is the code for the special effects
.box .inputBox input:valid ~ label
  {
    top: -18px;
    left: 0;
    color: #5100c9;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

.box input[type="submit"]{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background: #5100c9;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

   .box input[type="submit"]:hover{
       font-weight: bold;
     }
```

Comment: You will need to add a working code snippet here to demonstrate the issue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: how are you importing the css in react?

Comment: import  '../App.css;

Comment: the css for everything else is working fine except for the textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Robulus/pen/bGdzdZW) to test this and could see that this line in the css was causing an issue:

```
.box .inputBox input:focus ~ label,
.box .inputBox input:valid ~ label
```

The second selector in that line (`.box .inputBox input:valid ~ label`) is always true because

> The `:valid` selector only works for form elements with limitations, such as input elements with min and max attributes, email fields with a legal email, or number fields with a numeric value, etc.

This results in the `label` always sliding up and turning blue whether it has focus or not.

I simply removed `,
.box .inputBox input:valid ~ label`
from your css as shown in the codepen.

Your next challenge will be to keep the `label` from moving back to it's original position when the input loses focus. I think that is what you were trying to accomplish with the line I removed, but that is not the answer. This link https://zellwk.com/blog/check-empty-input-css/ should get you the rest of the way.

Comment: I did the same and removed that line as well and it works fine thanks